# Bootstrap on and off toggle switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
stream = $('#dash-stream');


streamCheck();
$(stream).click(function() {
    streamCheck();
});



function streamCheck() {
if ($(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
    $(stream).addClass('active-dash');
    $(".stream-section-hold").show();
    //loadPostsJson("load-stream", "#stream-holder", 1);
    loadStreamJson("true","true");

} else if (!$(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
    $(".stream-section-hold").hide();
    $(stream).removeClass('active-dash');
};
}
```

I have a `button` which will load a `div` containing an events stream, I want it to load `div`-content (the stream) on page load but be able to turn it on and off which will hide or show the content respectively. This currently loads content but does not have the `hide` and `show` functionality that I need. (Hide function isn't working.) What am I missing?

`dash-stream` is the button.

```
stream = $('#dash-stream');


streamCheck();
$(stream).click(function() {
    streamCheck();
});


function streamCheck() {

$(".stream-section-hold").show();

$('#dash-stream').click(function() {
    if (!$(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
        $(stream).addClass('active-dash');
        $(".stream-section-hold").show();
        //loadPostsJson("load-stream", "#stream-holder", 1);
        loadStreamJson("true", "true");

    } else if ($(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
        $(".stream-section-hold").hide();
        $(stream).removeClass('active-dash');
    };
});
}
```

This works but only on every second click.

Comment: You might have a Javascsript error.
Is this Javascript variable ("stream") defined ?
Because it's mentioned here: $(stream)

Comment: Make a JSFiddle for us to "fiddle" with and solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

```
loadStreamJson("true","true");

streamCheck();

$(stream).hasClass('active-dash');
$(stream).addClass('active-dash');
$(".stream-section-hold").show();

$(stream).click(function() {
    streamCheck();
});

function streamCheck() {

if (!$(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
    $(stream).addClass('active-dash');
    $(".stream-section-hold").show();
    //loadPostsJson("load-stream", "#stream-holder", 1);
    loadStreamJson("true","true");

} else if ($(stream).hasClass('active-dash')) {
    $(".stream-section-hold").hide();
    $(stream).removeClass('active-dash');
};
}
```